# Rewrite subdomain to domain fails for homepage only

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

This is about a WordPress site on shared hosting (mod_proxy module is not available). I need to rewrite (not redirect) https://sub.example.com to https://example.com. So, if requesting anything on https://sub.example.com, the browser should show what's served by https://example.com without changing the URL. The subdomain will serve as the origin for a CDN, that's why I need this.

SSL has been configured, the subdomain points to the directory of the main domain, and I added this to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,NC,L]
```

It works as desired, except for the homepage. A request to sub.example.com/directory/ correctly shows whatever there is on example.com/directory/ with HTTP status code 200. But a request to sub.example.com results in a 301-redirect to example.com.

How do I get the rewrite to work for the homepage as well?

Alternatively I tried this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain/. It allows multiple domains for a WordPress site, but it changes all links in the pages to the requested domain, which is not what I need. I need the exact content of the main domain to be returned, and got that working apart from the homepage.

Comment: I don’t see how there is any _actual_ problem here in the first place. You say you are using this subdomain as a CDN, and a CDN’s purpose generally is to serve in-page assets, not actual web pages or even the root page - so in what context would _just_ `sub.example.com` ever be requested in the first place? Assets are not usually served from `/`.

Comment: The rewrite configuration you have shown is only for an HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect. Which would once more beg the question, _if_ this was actually used as a CDN to serve assets, in what context would those be requested using HTTP in the first place?

Comment: _“the subdomain points to the directory of the main domain”_ - and how exactly was that achieved? Did you create any specific VHost configuration yourself, did you set this in some sort of hosting panel, …? The problem might lay at that point already.

Comment: @CBroe Indeed, a CDN is generally used for static assets, so that part works. However, I'd like to potentially cache entire pages, so that's when I would need the homepage too. I've actually done this on another website on a Microsoft server, and I'm now testing how this would work for a WordPress site.

Comment: @CBroe I see what you mean now. I should remove that first RewriteCond and see what happens then.

Comment: @CBroe That was done in the hosting account (Hpanel at Hostinger) by adding the subdomain and then filling out the directory it should serve files from.

Comment: I removed that first RewriteCond and could verify that the rule is executed, but still it does not work for the homepage. I think it's something in WordPress. It looks like if index.php is requested it always redirects to the main domain, and that happens after processing of htaccess, within WordPress.

Comment: "the subdomain points to the directory of the main domain" - it points to the same directory as the main domain, or points to a subdirectory off the main domain? When you specify an absolute URL in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ string it will _always_ trigger an external (302) redirect?

Comment: @MrWhite It points to the same directory as the main domain. This is what makes a request to sub.example.com/anything return the content of example.com/anything while staying on the requested URL, no redirect. It only fails for a request to sub.example.com, that redirects to example.com. Are you saying I should enter a path in the RewriteRule rather than an URL? Simply "/"?

Comment: In that case, you don't need any additional `RewriteRule` directives in `.htaccess`. As noted above, the rule you posted is an HTTP to HTTPS external 302 redirect on the same-domain (ie. subdomain to subdomain) - so it's not actually doing what you state anyway. I assume you've mistakenly put those directives at the end of the `.htaccess` file, so they aren't being processed for _most_ requests - which is most probably why it "appears" to be working.

Comment: If your entire site (not just your static assets) are accessible from the subdomain as well, then you'll need to configure WordPress itself to accept requests to both hosts. When you request the document-root then the default WP front-controller in `.htaccess` doesn't actually do anything, which is probably why you are seeing a different response for requests to the root.

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, correct. All except the request to the root works fine even without the rule in .htaccess. And a rule can't fix that problem. I'd probably have to mess with wp-config.php to get it working, but I won't do that. I'm going to accept that it works for 99% for now.